# Метод __str__ для поля с choices

Tags: python, django

Создана модель на Django, одно из полей которой заполняется при помощи объекта choices:

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    choices = tuple(enumerate(('A','B','C','D',)))

    select = models.IntegerField(
    choices = choices,
)
```

Подскажите, как в этом случае будет выглядеть метод `__str__` ?
Мой вариант не работает:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '<ABC ' \
        '#{self.id}: ' \
        '{selected}' \
    '>'.format(
        self = self,
        selected = self.choices[self.select][1],
    )
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99982/discussion-on-question-by----str----choices).

Answer (score 2):

```
def __str__(self):
    return '<ABC#{}: {}>'.format(self.id, self.get_select_display())
```

Comment: ваш вариант не подошёл 'ABC' object has no attribute 'get_select_display'  И в реальной модели полей больше (опущены), поэтому я использую переменную selected

Comment: @ЛёляЖужевна название метода должно соответствовать настоящему названию вашего поля. Например , `get_yourfield_display()`.